# How to parse a file with a multiple JSONs in PHP(Laravel)?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have input file that looks something like this:

```
{"name": "foo"}{"name": "bar"}
```

How to parse that?

Comment: not a valid json

Comment: I know that, but can i somehow transform it to valid json and than parse it? @PruthvirajChudasama

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure, that the individual JSONs are valid, you can try to transform it into an array of JSON objects, like this:

```
$data = '{"name": "foo"}{"name": "bar"}';

$data = str_replace('}{', '},{', $data);
$data = '[' . $data . ']';

// Now it's valid
// [{"name": "foo"},{"name": "bar"}]
```

Since `}{` is always invalid in JSON, it's safe to say, that it won't affect your data.

Comment: Thank you @JuhG. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

there are several way to parse json objects such as this .. but you must know the exact structure of that object ..

one way is to iterate each child ..

```
foreach($jsonObj as $obj)
{
    // access my name using
    $obj->name;
    $obj->someotherfield
    // or iterate again .. assuming each object has many more attribute
    foreach($obj as $key => $val)
    {
        //access my key using
        $key
        // access my value using
        $val
    }
}
```

there are tons of other ways to do that so .. and also , a valid json is like `[{"name": "foo"},{"name": "bar"}]`